# why is clock() function giving negative output?

Tags: c

i am trying to calculate efficiency of a c program. I am using cclock() function to calculate the time consumed in execution of the program.
This is the code
but i am getting negative output

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

clock_t start,end,total;
start = clock();
int i;
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",i);
}
end = clock();
printf("%0.2f",(start-end)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Measuring execution time is not the same as measuring efficiency. I believe there's an `FAQ` question about this.

Comment: Use a debugger will figure this out

Answer (score 3):

Use **end-start**, not **start-end**!

Answer (score 1):

`start - end` is subtracting the greater time from the lesser, hence why you're getting a negative value. It's like asking why you get a negative value when you subtract seven from three :-)

You need to subtract `start` from `end`.

---

As an aside, there's no guarantee that `clock_t` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are floating point types. If they're integral types, you're likely to end up with a integer division. If you really want a floating value, use something like:

```
(double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

There's a few other minor nigglies in your code, nothing major, but a cleaner implementation in my opinion would be along the following lines:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    clock_t duration = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf ("%d\n", i);
    duration = clock() - duration;
    printf ("%0.2f seconds\n", (double)(duration) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

---

As a second aside, outputting a thousand lines is likely to take about zero seconds CPU time on modern systems. I'm assuming your payload will be a little more complex but don't be surprised if that code above takes no CPU time at all (at least to two decimal places). In fact, I had to multiply the loop by a hundred to get it up to 0.3 seconds on my system.

And don't think you can get a larger duration by using something like `sleep()` since that will almost certainly not use any CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%0.2f",(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

It's simple maths. Do **end - start**.

Answer (score 0):

The ending time is after starting time.

You should change it to `printf("%0.2f",(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);`

Comment: thanx :)
but the answer wouldnt differ?

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to calculate the time consumed in execution of your program.